# 'ionic' command error after installing ionic and cordova on window

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, npm, window, installation

I installed ionic and cordova with "npm install -g cordova ionic " on window OS(window 10)

After installing, if I put  "ionic" on my cmd, the Error below was shown.

[image]

My node version is v12.16.3 and the npm version is 6.14.5.

Help me.

Comment: Please post errors as text, not as images.

Comment: npm install -g @ionic/core or @ionic/cli , i don't remeber which one exactly